Windows 10 randomly shut down because secure boot is disabled - how to prevent?
Having inspected Windows system logs come morning, I saws that around 6 AM my pc shut down because, quote,
The Secure Boot update failed to update a Secure Boot variable with error Secure Boot is not enabled on this machine.. For more information, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2169931

Event source: TPM-WMI
Event ID: 1796

How to prevent random shutdowns on Windows because secure boot is disabled? I imagine this has something to do with Windows trying to update itself during the night.
Unfortunately, switching to Linux is not possible at the moment.

I believe your shutdown issue is not caused by UEFI variable updates quoted in the log entry. It is the other way around: shutdown and reboot caused those entries to be logged. These UEFI variable updates are needed to mitigate the BlackLotus Secure Boot vulnerability (irrelevant to you since you disabled Secure Boot) and failure audit logs are printed on each boot.
Try to find other reasons for the shutdown. For example, search the logs for Bugcheck to see if any BSoD happened.
I also highly suspect it's just Windows Update automatically rebooting outside of your active hours. The July Patch Tuesday just passed and a reboot is very probable at 6 AM. Check Settings to see if any cumulative update installation happened on that day.
